# getting null all field response except id in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Hi Everyone i am creating on api for with nested serialization but getting null response of every
field except id, please help me out.

**models.py**

```
class Name(BaseModel):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)

class Role(BaseModel):
    role=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    name=models.ForeignKey(Name, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class RoleSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields= "__all__"


class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role=RoleSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['id','first_name','last_name','middle_name','role']
```

**views.py**

```
class Profile(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Role.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NameSerializer
```

**api response**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": null,
    "middle_name": null,
    "last_name": null,               
    "role": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": null
                 }
 }
```

Comment: What api is this response from?

Comment: @DavidLu i have mention what i am getting api response, i don't know why all fields getting null value.

Comment: I mean what api method exactly did u use?

Comment: @DavidLu get method

Comment: I think the database data is like that.

Comment: @DavidLu no in database i have already data, if no data in role then then its going to nestsed field in response

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but try something like this:

```
class Profile(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Name.objects.all().prefetch_related('role')
    serializer_class = NameSerializer

class NameSerializer(Serializer):
    role = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
    model = Name
    fields = ['id','first_name','last_name','middle_name','role']

    def get_role(self, obj):
        return obj.role.all().values_list('role', flat=True) # or Role.objects.filter(name=obj.id).values_list('role', flat=True)
```

If you want all the values on the Roll then you can change the get_role method to:

```
    def get_role(self, obj):
        return RoleSerializer(obj.role.all(), many=True)# or RoleSerializer(Role.objects.filter(name=obj.id), many=True)
```

I have not tried the code. So it might need some small changes.